# Instance state serializable loses data

Tags: android, android-activity

In one of Activities I have `HashSet<Integer> mSelectedPositions`. I want to save state of this set on screen rotation.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NotNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(SELECTED_TYPES_POSITIONS, mSelectedPositions);
}
```

And restore it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState!= null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(SELECTED_TYPES_POSITIONS)){
        mSelectedPositions = (HashSet<Integer>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(SELECTED_TYPES_POSITIONS);
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is, `getSerializable(..)` returns an empty `HashSet`, even then it wasn't empty in `putSerializable(..)`.

What's even weirder, I have almost the same code (with other keys) in other Fragments, and it works fine.

Don't know if matters, but activity in question is a child of MainActivity.

**Upd**

Part of the problem is in selection flow. On destroy of activity action mode is finished.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(mActionMode != null){
        mActionMode.finish();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Which triggers

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    mAdapter.clearSelections();
    mActivity.nullifyActionMode();
}
```

in `SelectionCallback`.

I think, next thing happens:
1. I put `mSelectedPositions` in `outState` Bundle, it stores reference
2. Activity is destroyed
3. SelectionCallback clears `mSelectedPositions`
4. Actual serialization happens with empty HashSet.

So I made some changes — new HashSet with copy of `mSelectedPositions` data

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(SELECTED_TYPES_POSITIONS, new HashSet<>(mSelectedPositions));
}
```

And it works like it should.

**Upd2**

In Fragments I call `mActionMode.finish()` in `onDetach()`, which is not called on screen rotation, so `mSelectedPositions` there remains intact.

Comment: If you want retain data on screen rotation consider using ViewModel to hold them. [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: @TheLibrarian please don't spread misconceptions, and read the docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options_for_preserving_ui_state your proposed solution is not equal in behavior and insufficient.

Comment: @TheLibrarian Thanks for advice! I am considering doing it like that. Also I want to understand, why `instance state` doesn't work in that Activity, but works in Fragments.

Comment: Kirill, this problem is a bit more esoteric, can you add more code regarding the class where this restoration fails? Also worth knowing if mSelectedPositions is actually `HashSet<Integer` because Bundle just returns null on a type mismatch.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce [Activity code](https://github.com/kirillsmirnov1/Friends-reminder-android/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/com/trulden/friends/activity/InteractionTypesActivity.java) on github.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The problem was in clearing `mSelectedPositions` before it was actually serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The funny thing is that serialization of `outState` happens after `onDestroy()` call. And I was erasing data passed to `outState` in `onDestroy`.

So, there are two ways to fix that:
• pass copy of data to `outState`
• don't erase data in `onDestroy`

Opted for second option. Erasing might be required in some cases in `onDetach()` of Fragments, but it is not necessary with Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a Json instead of raw HashMap

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NotNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(SELECTED_TYPES_POSITIONS,new Gson().toJson(mSelectedPositions));
}
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState!= null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(SELECTED_TYPES_POSITIONS)){
        String data = savedInstanceState.getString(SELECTED_TYPES_POSITIONS);
       if(data != null){
       mSelectedPositions = new Gson().fromJson(str, new TypeToken<HashSet<Integer>>() { }.getType())
     }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: you might need to put `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'` in dependencies in `build.gradle`

Comment: Theoretically the raw HashMap should also work, but this would be a good way to determine if it's really Serializable causing problems, or the HashSet is actually empty.

Comment: Tried that. `data` equals `[0]`.

Comment: oops sorry, try `outState.putString` instead... check edit